# Vmware-clarity and Visual Studio 2017 Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0, vmware-clarity

I started to have a look at Clarity few days ago. And it seems good to link clarity and net core 2.0 to have Windows Authentication in VS2017 solution combined with IIS

Does vmware-clarity import and launch successfully with Visual Studio 2017 net core 2.0 projects with Angular 4.2.5? 
Or it needs to be upgraded to 5.0.0/5.2.0?
Latest angular is 6.0.0. @clr/angular has the dependencie on angular ^5.0.0. What is the correct version for latest clarity 0.11.6?

Answer (score 1):

Yeap! It works great!
So when I choose the newest VS 2017 15.7.1 release which has been published last night, .Net Core 2.1 Preview. And create new Project it creates Angular 5.2 webapp.
And all clarity libraries imported successfully.